# Can't instantiate objects using cli python interpreter

Tags: python

Can't instantiate objects using python interpreter, please help.
So inside of my python file `expresser.py` I have something like

```
class Expresser:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    ...
```

Now when I type in the terminal
`python`
and then

`>>> import expresser`

`>>> test_object = Expresser()`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Expresser' is not defined
```

- I'm using PyCharm
- when I type `where python` I get three diff locations so I suspect that but don't know how to rectify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you meant:

```
from expresser import Expresser
```

Or:

```
from expresser import *
```